# How to access the variables from inside a function in Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

```
      export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('googleMap') gmapElement: any;
      map: google.maps.Map;  
      data = "initialised";

      ngOnInit() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

          var map =  new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
                zoom: 7,
                center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
          });
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          directionsService.route({
              origin: "terrell hills, tx",
              destination: "alamo heights, tx",
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            },  (response, status) => {
              if (String(status) === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService";
    /**********************************************************
Here the directions are displaying correctly but `this.data`'s value is not changing. What is the reason?
************************************************************/
              } else {
                alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
     }
```

HTML

```
<span>{{data}}</span> <!---------Here data is always showing as `initialised`, but directions are displaying perfectly---------->
```

The  class member `data`'s value is not changing inside the function even after using arrow function. The value of `data` is always showing `initialised`. Can someone please check the comment in the code and please tell me the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: console.log(this.data) above this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService"; and see if it is undefined

Comment: it's not showing `undefined` instead showing **initialised** , and adding console.log(this.data) below this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService"; showing I'm modified in directionsService. But the 2 way binding is not working, the value of <span>{{data}}</span> is always initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }
```

modify this portion

```
          if (String(status) === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService";
            //this.cdr.markForCheck(); // Changed
            this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
          } else {
            alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
```

Comment: Sorry @Franklin Pious Some output. Nothing changed. :(

Comment: Is it possible to provide a stackblitz of the similar code? @Doe

Comment: It's just an Angular CLI Skelton app with only one component and this is that component. @Franklin Pious

Comment: Thank you @Franklin Pious It was solved using `this.cdr.detectChanges();` instead of `this.cdr.markForCheck()`